# Access angular controller from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I have a controller inside my html

```
<div ng-controller="myController" id="myCtrl">...</div>
```

I can access it via:

```
angular.element(myCtrl).controller()
```

But how can I access the controller from a directive?

```
 directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        ...
        templateUrl: '/Views/myview.html',
        controller: myController
    }
})
```

Comment: Why do you want to access the controller ???

Comment: i have a weird architecture ;)

Comment: are you trying to declare what controller the directive should use dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This controller should be defined the same module module where your directive is defined:

E.g

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myController',['$scope', function($scope){
     $scope.myData = {'someData':1337};
}])

.directive('myDirective', [function(){
    return {
        ...
        templateUrl: '/Views/myview.html',
        controller: 'myController'
    }
}])
```

Here is a plunkr, demonstrating that way:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UDCWUI5EMlfoXb9u3GYh?p=preview

And here is a plunkr, demonstrating having a directive in a module using a controller that is defined in another module:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gg0BzKPOqO2NnTgf3Hkr?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp',[
])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.someValue = 'someValueFromController';
}])

angular.module('otherModule', ['myApp'])

.directive('myDirective', [function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'someTemplate.html',
      controller: 'MyController'
   }
}])
```

Alternatively, you can use the [$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24controller) service to instantiate your controller with the appropriate stuffs and use it everywhere (from every module that imports the module where your controller is defined).